# How do I create a bookmark in chrome that gives a popup to append a URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I would like to create a bookmark in chrome that when clicked will display a popup window for text input. Take that input and append to a URL.

Example:
The URL I would like to append

https://store.com/admin/tableviewer.asp?table=Discounts&IsASearch=Y&submit.search.x=search&CouponCode=

Then a POPUP window asking for input - "sweet"

Resulting URL

https://store.com/admin/tableviewer.asp?table=Discounts&IsASearch=Y&submit.search.x=search&CouponCode=**sweet**

Comment: You want to redirect to the desired link?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this support article for how to do this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1200286

`javascript:window.location = "https://mycompany" + prompt("enter string:");`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You can use the built-in [window.prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) (or just `prompt()`) Function. It opens an alert with input and returns the value you put it. I assume you want to redirect to the desired link, so you redirect by setting `window.location` to your desired location.

Look at this demo:

```js
const word = prompt("Please enter value", "sweet");
const url = 'https://store.com/admin/tableviewer.asp?table=Discounts&IsASearch=Y&submit.search.x=search&CouponCode=';

if (word) {
  window.location = url + word;
}
```